# Is position:fixed working well in Internet Explorer 7-8-9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I was wondering if position:fixed is working well in Microsoft browsers, before to start to use it.

thanks

Comment: did u try correcting your doctype ?
I resolved using that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixed` didn't work in IE6, but in my experience is fine since 7.

Quirksmode.org has [one caveat](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html):

> In IE7, if you select "absolute" or "fixed" and then "relative", most of the layer’s content doesn’t show.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by putting in this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
```

Take a look in the following [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Those are fine according to quirksmode.org.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [website that can help you to know more about the compatibility](http://caniuse.com/).

Answer (score 0):

*Note that IE 7 from beta 2 upwards does support position: fixed; (if you use a document type declaration that triggers strict mode)*

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/fixedPosition.html

Answer (score -1):

I use position absolute to work in all browsers.
And to get the same result as of 'fixed', I use in css

```
top: $(document).scrollTop() + 225 +'px'
```

It works properly in all browsers.